# How to start a mysql column with a specific increment value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In mysql table i have a column named invoice_id . Where i manually input the Invoice No (Which is int only) . It has arbitrary values like 111, 5545, 5655 etc

Now i want it to be a unique auto increment value. Which will start from 9000 . 
But i also want that previous values will stay as well .

Any idea how i can change the mysql table ? Check the attached image for more details

[Invoice_no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAfAc.png)

Comment: Do you know if you already have some invoice_id 9000 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE invoice AUTO_INCREMENT = 9000;
```

For more info look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: You mean `= 9000`, because that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee  So like this 
ALTER TABLE ledger MODIFY invoice_no AUTO_INCREMENT = 9000;
where ledger is my table name and invoice_no is the column name ?

Comment: No only the way I posted in the answer. Look at the link I included. `ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 13;`

Comment: @MosarofHossain Do NOT do this. Despite its name, the autoincrement feature is not for adding incrementing numbers to a series. It serves no other purpose other than to establish that numbers in a column are unique, and sequential (the fact that they are incremental is arbitrary and often ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,invoice_no INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO my_table (invoice_no) VALUES (111),(5545),(5655);

INSERT INTO my_table (invoice_no) VALUES (9000);

INSERT INTO my_table (invoice_no) SELECT MAX(invoice_no +1) FROM my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+
| id | invoice_no |
+----+------------+
|  1 |        111 |
|  2 |       5545 |
|  3 |       5655 |
|  4 |       9000 |
|  5 |       9001 |
+----+------------+

INSERT INTO my_table (invoice_no) SELECT MAX(invoice_no +1) FROM my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+
| id | invoice_no |
+----+------------+
|  1 |        111 |
|  2 |       5545 |
|  3 |       5655 |
|  4 |       9000 |
|  5 |       9001 |
|  6 |       9002 |
+----+------------+
```